# Where Database Alerts & Operators Exist In SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

My SQL Server database server has crashed. I have system databases backup. I will reinstall the sql server but i don't know how to find my operators, alerts and config settings. Is there a way to find it? I have master, model and msdb system backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all in msdb.  Note that the new server must be at *exactly* the same version to restore a system database.

> System databases can be restored only from backups that are created on
>   the version of SQL Server that the server instance is currently
>   running. For example, to restore a system database on a server
>   instance that is running on SQL Server 2012 (11.x) SP1, you must use a
>   database backup that was created after the server instance was
>   upgraded to SQL Server 2012 (11.x) SP1.

[Backup & restore: system databases - Limitations on Restoring System Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-system-databases-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-on-restoring-system-databases)

Comment: OK. Which tables contain those alerts and operators informations? How can i get them?

Comment: You can restore msdb, or script them out (possibly after restoring msdb on some other server).

Comment: Thank you very much @David Browne !